# How i can to get a search by all fields in entity Spring Data Jpa

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have an entity sensor.
How i can to do a search by all fields (include type and unit), because now i get a result only by (id, name, model, .., location, description)
I use Spring Data Jpa

```
    @Query("SELECT s " +
            "FROM Sensor s " +
            "WHERE CONCAT(s.name, s.model, s.rangeFrom, s.rangeTo, s.location, s.description, 
             s.type, s.unit) " +
            "LIKE %:text%")
    List<Sensor> findAllSensorsByText(@Param("text") String text);
```

**Sensor class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sensors")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Sensor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "sensor_id")
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String model;
    @Column(name = "range_from")
    private Integer rangeFrom;
    @Column(name = "range_to")
    private Integer rangeTo;
    private String location;
    private String description;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "type_id")
    private Type type;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "unit_id")
    private Unit unit;
}
```

**Type class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "types")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Type {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "type_id")
    private Integer id;
    private String type;
}
```

**Unit class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "units")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Unit {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "unit_id")
    private Integer id;
    private String unit;
}
```

Comment: @xerx593 the problem is that the fields are in other tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you shouldn't just concatenate the fields.
If one field contains `"abc"` and the next contains `"def"` you will actually find a match for `"bcde"` although you shouldn't.

Instead use `or`.

For `Type` and `Unit` you can simply navigate the relationship using JPQL:

```sql
SELECT s 
FROM Sensor s 
WHERE 
s.name LIKE %:text%
OR s.model LIKE %:text%
OR s.rangeFrom LIKE %:text%
OR s.rangeTo LIKE %:text%
OR s.location LIKE %:text%
OR s.description LIKE %:text%
OR s.type.type LIKE %:text%
OR s.unit.unit LIKE %:text%
```

Depending on your exact requirements you might be able to switch to `=` instead of `LIKE` for some conditions, which would allow the usage of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `s.*` in the `CONCAT` statment to get all the fields, but it works only for native query.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT s.* FROM Sensor s WHERE CONCAT(s.*) LIKE %:text%" , nativeQuery = true)
List<Sensor> findAllSensorsByText(@Param("text") String text);
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me (doesn't respect fields in ohter tables type, units)